# how to save records in pivot table after checking the records in pivot table for duplication in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a products table and pivot table product collection. Now i want to save only the records in the pivot table that does,t contains any duplicate entry in pivot table from product table .

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You cab use `sync()` method to avoid duplicate entry. This method will remove the old records that doesn't exits in form data and it add new rows if the form data have new values.